# Push holidays in users' calendar

Tags: rest, oauth, calendar, office365

In our current environment, our employees book holidays in an SAP portal. There's a separate script that will send these holidays to the users' email calendar (currently Zimbra), so it's already filled in.

Now we're currently migrating to Office 365, and we need to change our script. First glance was good, there's a pretty solid REST API available with methods that will do the job just fine.

Unfortunately, the whole thing requires OAuth2. In our scenario, we won't be having any user interaction, we'd really want to use static credentials.

I've been doing some googling, but to no avail. Is there a proper solution to our use case, without having to do anything dirty?

Side-note: we'd like to use Java to get this done. But I find even less documentation about that. The EWS API looks like a potential solution, but it looks pretty deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OAuth with the client credentials flow. This involves an administrator interacting once to consent to allow the app to access all calendars in the organization. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/ for details.